# How do I reset the AUTO_INCREMENT constraint for `django_apscheduler_djangojobexecution` table?

Tags: mysql, apscheduler, django-3.0

I'm trying to run a job that deletes the records from `django_apscheduler_djangojobexecution` table (I'm using MySQL on XAMPP). This is the portion of the code I'm using:

```
from django.db import connection
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore, register_events, register_job

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")
db_cursor = connection.cursor()

@register_job(scheduler, "interval", seconds=15)
def clear_scheduler_log():
    db_cursor.execute("DELETE FROM `django_apscheduler_djangojobexecution`; ALTER TABLE `django_apscheduler_djangojobexecution` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;")

register_events(scheduler)
```

I've even tried interchanging the `DELETE` and `ALTER` queries, but problem is still the same;
The job is deleting the records, but not at all resetting `AUTO_INCREMENT` to 1. But when I execute the same in django shell, it is able to reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

What can I do to reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` constraint within the scheduler

Comment: Hint: `TRUNCATE` table.

Comment: @mitkosoft. Thanks, this seems to work as intended